# I have single .ini file need to read two sections using Autoit

Tags: autoit

I have file called `a.ini` containing two section :

```
[Section1]
name1=abc
name2=xyz
name3=def

[Section2]
class1=1st
class2=2nd
class3=3rd
```

I want to get this in to following output using autoit:

```
abc 1st
xyz 2nd
def 3rd
```

With the following code I am getting only `abc`, `xyz`, `def`. How do I read at the same time from both sections simultaneously?

```
Local $var = IniReadSection(@ScriptDir & "a.ini", "section1")
If @error Then
    MsgBox(4096, "", "Error occurred, probably no INI file.")
Else
    For $i = 1 To $var[0][0]
        MsgBox(4096, "", "Key: " & $var[$i][0] & @CRLF & "Value: " & $var[$i][1])
    Next
EndIf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The folowing code will read all sections using **IniReadSectionNames** and then while looping on each section, read it with **IniReadSection**.

```
Local $sections = IniReadSectionNames(@WindowsDir & "\win.ini")
If @error Then
    MsgBox(4096, "", "Error occurred, probably no INI file.")
Else
    For $i = 1 To $sections[0]

        Local $values = IniReadSection(@WindowsDir & "\win.ini", $sections[$i])
        If @error Then
            ConsoleWrite("SECTION " & $sections[$i] & ": is EMPTY!" & @LF)
            ContinueLoop
        EndIf
        For $i2 = 1 To $values[0][0]
            ConsoleWrite("SECTION " & $sections[$i] & ": Key: " & $values[$i2][0] & "=" & $values[$i2][1] & @LF)
        Next

    Next
EndIf
```

Comment: I edited it just now because it had some flaws.
Make sure you protect it against empty sections.
You're welcome :)